# Oracle sql : read/write to CSV files using sql

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, utl-file

By using SQL, I need to read data from a CSV file that contains rows of 3 values and then use it in a WHERE clause in a SELECT statement, after that dump the results of the SELECT (7 fields in total) in a new CSV file.

The query looks like :

```
SELECT
    COL_1,
    COL_2,
    COL_3,
    COL_4
    ...
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    COL_1 = *INFO_FROM_CSV*
    COL_2 = *INFO_FROM_CSV*
    ...
```

> I am using now **UTL_FILE** to read the data and store it in a new table, then using **SPOOL** to export it, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Using [`SQL Loader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-concepts.html#GUID-0A3FE221-01B5-4CDD-9834-109B3BB3B16D) is still a very good way during the import.

Comment: How often will this process run?  How many files in each run?  How many rows per file?

Comment: @Gary_W It will run manually by launching a VB script, and for the input it will be one CSV file. About rows it depends on another system, but mostly it will not exceed 30000 rows

Comment: Maybe you could consider something like here ( https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml )

Comment: Check out external tables. It lets you query a flat file as if it was a true table.  Then using SQLcl or "set markup csv" in SQL*Plus you can spool output to a CSV file easily as well